# Datediff without Weekends

Tags: c#

A short explanation what I do: I have a chart, where i show a Label for the Min and Max Value. If the appropriate Extrema are on the right side of the chart, the Label is aligned left. (If it's left, then the label is aligned right) The Y-Axis has timestamsp, so I calculate the Datediff, to align the Label.

```
minPos = (minTupel.Value.Time - srtTupel.Value.Time) 
          > (endTupel.Value.Time - minTupel.Value.Time) 
          ? "Left" : "Right";

maxPos = (maxTupel.Value.Time - srtTupel.Value.Time) 
          > (endTupel.Value.Time - maxTupel.Value.Time) 
          ? "Left" : "Right";
```

But the chart ignores the weekends, because there are no values. If I calculate the difference between Thursday and Monday, the result is 4 Days, but the chart only shows 2. Therefore the label is aligned right, when it should be left. Is there any option to get the Datediff without the Weekends?

Comment: Just assume that any contiguous 7-day period will contain two weekend days, and then handle the edge case of < 7 days by looking at the day of week of each date.

Comment: This could easily escalate to a complex matter. What about holidays that are not on weekends?

Comment: @Steve The dupe I linked handles holidays too

Comment: @DavidG yes I was just looking at it, great answer. Closing this now

Comment: @Steve I don't see holidays in this question. Maybe the linked answer is overkill.

Comment: @KeithPayne it is really easy to adapt

Comment: Thanks! I haven't found this question in the search, but it really saves me time.